# sqlalchemy listens_for() doesn't trigger

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have working listens_for function, which inserts `LoadHistory` object before updating `Load`:

```
@event.listens_for(Load, 'before_update')
def before_update_load(mapper, connection, target):
    current_load_select = select(load_fields).where(Load.id == target.id)
    insert_history = insert(LoadHistory).from_select(load_history_fields, current_load_select)
    connection.execute(insert_history)
```

And the task is to have similar function but which will insert `LoadStopHistory` objects after `LoadHistory` object has been inserted. The code is:

```
@event.listens_for(LoadHistory, 'after_insert')
def after_insert_load_history(mapper, connection, target):
    # here will be code
    print("@" * 125)
    print('trgt', target)
    print("@" * 125)
```

but the issue that this function has never been called.
I've tried to insert `LoadHistory` with updating `Load` or directly with Postgres, neither practice had any result.
I've tried with 'after_insert' changed to 'before_insert' and 'before_update'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The impression I get from this note (from [Mapper-level Flush Events](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_events.html#mapper-level-flush-events)):

> It is important to note that these events apply only to the session flush operation , and not to the ORM-level INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE functionality described at ORM-Enabled INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements. To intercept ORM-level DML, use the SessionEvents.do_orm_execute() event.

is that the **after_insert** event will not register the result of calling `insert()` directly - the **do_orm_execute** listener must be used instead. Moreover, the insert should be executed using the session rather than the connection to be registered by the ORM event machinery.

These listeners seem to work:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

...

@sa.event.listens_for(Load, 'before_update')
def before_update_load(mapper, connection, target):
    insert_history = sa.insert(LoadHistory)
    session = sa.inspect(target).session
    session.execute(insert_history)

@sa.event.listens_for(Session, 'do_orm_execute')
def receive_orm_execute(orm_execute_state):
    if (
        orm_execute_state.is_insert
        and orm_execute_state.statement.table.name
        == LoadHistory.__table__.name
    ):
        print('*' * 10)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are various possible causes to look into if your event listener for the `after_insert` event on the `LoadHistory` model is not being called. The relationships between your SQLAlchemy models (`Load`, `LoadHistory`, and `LoadStopHistory`) should be properly specified first because events may not occur in the absence of such relationships. Second, keep in mind that events are frequently started during the SQLAlchemy session commit, so be sure to do so after entering a "LoadHistory" object. Make that your event listeners are registered correctly and are executed when your application launches. Be mindful of database transactions; if one is reversed before the session commits, it may prevent events from happening.

Hope this helps, do let me know if you want help